# How long before I can have tile installed over new cement floor?

Tags: concrete

This 1970's house has a step-down (about 6") living room floor. Like others who have posted such a situation here, I would like this floor raised to be level with the rest of the house. It measures 18'x23' and has a stem wall all around...so essentially filling in a large boxed area.

I'd like to have it raised with concrete, but have found much conflicting information on how long it will need to "cure" before tile can be laid on top of it! And I have not found that answer to  any question here about sunken floors.

An internet search indicates 28 days, but one contractor I contacted says minimum a month, preferably more (using a 3000psi mix); another indicates 7-10 days (he uses 3500psi, as dry as possible and paints the existing slab underneath with a waterproofing product).
A third contractor uses 3250psi and says at least 2 weeks time before tiling.

None are open to using a light weight, quick drying cement. And then there are products such as water proofing and decoupling mats that can be installed under tile to mitigate water issues from uncured cement. (But where does the water go...?)

So the question is, is there a reliable formula for how long this floor would need to cure before I can put a subfloor on it, given it's inside the house with an AC running to keep humidity at about 50%. Does it really need 30 days? Or 7-10?

Comment: What is under this floor?  Hope it is a cement pad to hold the greater weight.  Could lay tile in a couple of days if you use 2x4 joists and lay sheets of plywood on top.  Cement should have ~28 days to cure.  Sealing that much cement up before could be iffy.

Comment: The "sunken" floor is built into the existing slab...so yes, there is cement under it. Using wood is certainly an option, though wood has gotten very expensive, so I'll have to review the cost difference.

Comment: Agree with @crip659 - framing it up and laying a plywood subfloor would be so much faster, probably cheaper, and give you the ability to add a secret hidey-hole for valuables. :)

Comment: If you go with concrete I'm glad you mentioned a decoupling membrane. I just had a house built and the tile was laid directly over the concrete (which had probably cured for 4 months or so) and the concrete cracked in the control cut. The tile cracked right along with it. Good thing we had some spare tile.